# django namespace NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-urls

I can't figure out what I've done wrong here. I'm using Django 1.6.5 with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have a project called research containing an app called notecards. Here is my research/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'research.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^notecards/', include('notecards.urls', namespace='notecards')),
)
```

And here is the call to it in notecards/views.py

```
def new_note(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = NotecardForm()
    else:
        form = NotecardForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            source = form.cleaned_data['source']
            page = form.cleaned_data['page']
            tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('notecards:index', ()))

    return render(request, 'notecards/new_note.html', {'form': form,
    })
```

And here is the error I'm getting: u'notecards' is not a registered namespace. I must be missing something obvious, and yet I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, change the `reverse('notecards:index', ())` to `reverse('notecards:index')`. The signature of `reverse` is

```
reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, prefix=None, current_app=None)
```

You could see that `urlconf` mistakenly takes `()` instead of `args` taking it.

Moreover, have a look at the `django.shortcuts.resolve_url`, it's easier for normal use.